# Why is the first code different than second?

Tags: c, variables

I'm at the lowest level and really trying to learn C, but I just can't figure out how this works.

```
char name[20] = "Dummy Text";
name[0]='M';
printf("%s", name);
```

This works perfectly and changes the D to M in the text.

```
char name[20];
name[20]="Dummy Text";
name[0]='M';
printf("%s", name);
```

This only prints M. 
Why is it that if I set the value of the variable later than when I declare it, it works different? With numbers it works alright from what I've seen.

Comment: `name[20]` is a `char` you can not assign a string to it

Comment: `name[20]` is also past the end of the array. After the declaration of the array, you can update the array with a copy operation (e.g. `strcpy(name, "Dummy Text")`) but you cannot use an assignment statement to copy a string literal into the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char name[20] = "Dummy Text";
```

That is initialization of the character array. The string "Dummy Text" is stored in this array as below:

```
name[0] = 'D'
name[1] = 'u'
name[2] = 'm'
name[3] = 'm'
name[4] = 'y'
name[5] = ' '
name[6] = 'T'
name[7] = 'e'
name[8] = 'x'
name[9] = 't'
name[10] = '\0'
```

The second declaration:

```
char name[20];
name[20]="Dummy Text";
```

You declare one character array that can content of 20 elements with character type. But this line `name[20]="Dummy Text"`, you try to assign string `Dummy Text` to character value. It's undefined behavior.

`name[20]` is also undefined behavior because the maximum index you can use for this array is `19` (from `0` to `19`).

If you want to copy string, you can use `strcpy` function, for example

```
strcpy(name, "Dummy Text");
```

Now, two program will print the same string: `Mummy Text`

Comment: Got it. Just thought that i can initialize later in the code and didnt make sense to me why not. With numbers its the same if i say int x; x=5; or int x=5;

Answer (score 1):

```
char name[20];
name[20]="Dummy Text";
```

This doesn't do what you expect for two reasons:

1. `name` is indexed from 0 to 19 - the element `name[20]` is beyond the end of the array.
2. You can't assign strings (or other array expressions) using the `=` operator.  You *should* get a diagnostic from the compiler along the lines of "you can't assign a `char *` to a `char`".

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to T" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

The *initialization*

```
char name[20] = "Dummy Text";
```

copies the contents of the string literal `"Dummy Text"` to the `name` array.  However, that *only* works in a declaration.  If you wrote

```
char name[20];
name = "Dummy Text";
```

then you're not copying the contents of the string literal to the array - you're trying to assign the pointer to the first character of the string literal to the array.  Again, you should get a diagnostic from the compiler complaining about this.

If you want to copy the contents of a string literal (or a string stored in a `char` array) to another array, you'll need to use the `strcpy` library function:

```
strcpy( name, "Dummy Text" );
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the first code different than second?

`char name[20] = "Dummy Text";`

is a character array initialization

while

`name[20]="Dummy Text";`

is an array element assignment just like how you are assigning 'M` to the first element by specifying

`name[0]='M';`

Comment: @FiddlingBits, it might not cause a warning or a run time error. It might just be an undefined behavior. However, I am just trying to answer OP's question about how two programs are different without going into details of what's wrong with the second one.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by: "while `name[20]="Dummy Text";` is an array element assignment just like how you are assigning `M`". `name[20]="Dummy Text"`; should result in a warning at the least.

Comment: Not only it will cause a warning, but it is also an out of bounds assignment  (writing the 21th element of a 20 elements array).

Comment: @RobertoCaboni, it may not cause any of that.